# With or without "would", what's the difference?

Tags: grammar, modal-verbs, auxiliary-verbs

I have been struggling with the "would" for quite a long time.
I know most of the basic ideas of would. But there are too many "extended usages" that always confuse me.

I found [this article from EnglishClub](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verbs-modal-would.htm) which is very helpful for understanding "would."

But still, I can't figure out what could be the difference without using the "would."

For example (sentence after the '→' is what I thought was "the same" meaning):

> #### would for desire or inclination
>
> - I'd love to live here.  → I love to live here.
> - Would you like some coffee?  → Do you like some coffee?
> - What I'd really like is some tea.  → What I really like is some tea.
>
> #### would for opinion or hope
>
> - I would imagine that they'll buy a new one.  → I can imagine that they'll buy a new one.
> - I suppose some people would call it torture.  → I suppose some people can call it torture.
> - I would have to agree.  → I have to agree.
> - I would expect him to come.  → I expect him to come.
> - Since you ask me I'd say the blue one is best.  → Since you ask me I have to say the blue one is best.
>
> #### would for presumption or expectation
>
> - That would be Jo calling. I'll answer it.  → That must/will be Jo calling.
> - We saw a police helicopter overhead yesterday morning. | Really? They would have been looking for those bank robbers.  → Really? They may have been looking for those bank robbers.

I just can't understand WHY it should be "would" rather than other word or without using "would". What is the difference there?

I really wish there is some sort of "core concept" that can help me to understand "would" once and for all.

Thanks!

Comment: By using "would", you can imply politeness or convey to a reader that you are talking about a hypothetical situation, not facts! Also, "must", "could", "would" imply different degrees of strictness! IMHO. I think this question is a little bit broad!

Comment: The 'core concept' is that *would* is related to *will*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you have it down pretty good for the second and third categories. I would recommend a slight change in this one:

> • I suppose some people would call it torture. →
>     I suppose some people <strike>can</strike> **might**  call it torture.

but other than that, I think you're getting the hang of it.

However, the first ones aren't equivalent at all – though I'm not sure if the faulty understanding is with *would*, or with the verbs *like* and *love*. Here's how I might paraphrase these:

> • Would you like some coffee? → Do you <strike>like</strike> **want** some coffee?
>   • What I'd really like is some tea. → What I really <strike>like</strike> **want** is some tea.
>   • I'd love to live here. → I <strike>love to</strike> **wish I could** live here.

In these cases, *would like* is a lot like *want*, it describes what you are are wanting or craving at the moment, but do not have yet (or cannot attain for some reason).

Answer (score 0):

Think *indirectness* or *politeness* when you encounter a would that as far as you can tell is not doing any useful grammatical work.